# Why does my PWM function work outside the interrupt but not if its called from the inside?

Tags: c, arm, stm32

I'm using a stm32L052 chip on a custom board. I'm working with HAL and can't seem to get the PWM to work after an interrupt has happened (button press). If I do a `HAL_PWM_START()` in the main loop, it works fine, but, if the interrupt calls it, it doesn't work.

*main.c*

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : main.c
  * @brief          : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * <h2><center>&copy; Copyright (c) 2020 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.</center></h2>
  *
  * This software component is licensed by ST under BSD 3-Clause license,
  * the "License"; You may not use this file except in compliance with the
  * License. You may obtain a copy of the License at:
  *                        opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* USER CODE END Header */

/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"
#include "usb_device.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "Remote.h"
/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */
/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
RTC_HandleTypeDef hrtc;

TIM_HandleTypeDef htim2;
TIM_HandleTypeDef htim6;

UART_HandleTypeDef huart1;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_RTC_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM2_Init(void);
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM6_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */


  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_RTC_Init();
  MX_TIM2_Init();
  MX_USB_DEVICE_Init();
  MX_USART1_UART_Init();
  MX_TIM6_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  /* USER CODE END 2 */



  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  sendData(0x57e3e817);
  while (1)
  {
      HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOB, LED_IND_Pin);
      HAL_Delay(1000);
      HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim2, TIM_CHANNEL_1);
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_PeriphCLKInitTypeDef PeriphClkInit = {0};

  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage 
  */
  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);
  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI|RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_LSI
                              |RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI48;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.LSIState = RCC_LSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSI48State = RCC_HSI48_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLMUL = RCC_PLLMUL_3;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLDIV = RCC_PLLDIV_2;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  PeriphClkInit.PeriphClockSelection = RCC_PERIPHCLK_USART1|RCC_PERIPHCLK_RTC
                              |RCC_PERIPHCLK_USB;
  PeriphClkInit.Usart1ClockSelection = RCC_USART1CLKSOURCE_PCLK2;
  PeriphClkInit.RTCClockSelection = RCC_RTCCLKSOURCE_LSI;
  PeriphClkInit.UsbClockSelection = RCC_USBCLKSOURCE_HSI48;
  if (HAL_RCCEx_PeriphCLKConfig(&PeriphClkInit) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief RTC Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_RTC_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTC_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END RTC_Init 0 */

  RTC_TimeTypeDef sTime = {0};
  RTC_DateTypeDef sDate = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTC_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END RTC_Init 1 */
  /** Initialize RTC Only 
  */
  hrtc.Instance = RTC;
  hrtc.Init.HourFormat = RTC_HOURFORMAT_24;
  hrtc.Init.AsynchPrediv = 127;
  hrtc.Init.SynchPrediv = 255;
  hrtc.Init.OutPut = RTC_OUTPUT_DISABLE;
  hrtc.Init.OutPutRemap = RTC_OUTPUT_REMAP_NONE;
  hrtc.Init.OutPutPolarity = RTC_OUTPUT_POLARITY_HIGH;
  hrtc.Init.OutPutType = RTC_OUTPUT_TYPE_OPENDRAIN;
  if (HAL_RTC_Init(&hrtc) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Check_RTC_BKUP */

  /* USER CODE END Check_RTC_BKUP */

  /** Initialize RTC and set the Time and Date 
  */
  sTime.Hours = 0x0;
  sTime.Minutes = 0x0;
  sTime.Seconds = 0x0;
  sTime.DayLightSaving = RTC_DAYLIGHTSAVING_NONE;
  sTime.StoreOperation = RTC_STOREOPERATION_RESET;
  if (HAL_RTC_SetTime(&hrtc, &sTime, RTC_FORMAT_BCD) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sDate.WeekDay = RTC_WEEKDAY_MONDAY;
  sDate.Month = RTC_MONTH_JANUARY;
  sDate.Date = 0x1;
  sDate.Year = 0x0;

  if (HAL_RTC_SetDate(&hrtc, &sDate, RTC_FORMAT_BCD) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTC_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END RTC_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief TIM2 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_TIM2_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM2_Init 0 */

  TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig = {0};
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};
  TIM_OC_InitTypeDef sConfigOC = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM2_Init 1 */
  htim2.Instance = TIM2;
  htim2.Init.Prescaler = 4;
  htim2.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim2.Init.Period = 126;
  htim2.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim2.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
  if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim2, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_Init(&htim2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim2, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sConfigOC.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_PWM1;
  sConfigOC.Pulse = 38;
  sConfigOC.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sConfigOC.OCFastMode = TIM_OCFAST_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim2, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM2_Init 2 */
  HAL_TIM_MspPostInit(&htim2);

}

/**
  * @brief TIM6 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_TIM6_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM6_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM6_Init 0 */

  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM6_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM6_Init 1 */
  htim6.Instance = TIM6;
  htim6.Init.Prescaler = 24;
  htim6.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim6.Init.Period = 500;
  htim6.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim6) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_TIM_OnePulse_Init(&htim6, TIM_OPMODE_SINGLE) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim6, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM6_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM6_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief USART1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 1 */
  huart1.Instance = USART1;
  huart1.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
  huart1.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart1.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart1.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart1.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart1.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart1.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  huart1.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
  huart1.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED_IND_GPIO_Port, LED_IND_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : MF1_Pin MF2_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = MF1_Pin|MF2_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLDOWN;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : MF3_Pin MF5_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = MF3_Pin|MF5_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLDOWN;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PWR_Pin BCK_Pin HOME_Pin UP_Pin 
                           RGT_Pin LFT_Pin V__Pin V_A9_Pin 
                           MUTE_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = PWR_Pin|BCK_Pin|HOME_Pin|UP_Pin 
                          |RGT_Pin|LFT_Pin|V__Pin|V_A9_Pin 
                          |MUTE_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_IT_RISING;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLDOWN;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : DWN_Pin OK_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = DWN_Pin|OK_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_IT_RISING;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLDOWN;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : MF4_Pin USB_SENSE_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = MF4_Pin|USB_SENSE_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLDOWN;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : LED_IND_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = LED_IND_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLDOWN;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(LED_IND_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /* EXTI interrupt init*/
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(EXTI0_1_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI0_1_IRQn);

  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(EXTI2_3_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI2_3_IRQn);

  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(EXTI4_15_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI4_15_IRQn);

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */

  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{ 
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     tex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */

/************************ (C) COPYRIGHT STMicroelectronics *****END OF FILE****/
```

*stm32l0xx.c*

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file    stm32l0xx_it.c
  * @brief   Interrupt Service Routines.
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * <h2><center>&copy; Copyright (c) 2020 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.</center></h2>
  *
  * This software component is licensed by ST under BSD 3-Clause license,
  * the "License"; You may not use this file except in compliance with the
  * License. You may obtain a copy of the License at:
  *                        opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* USER CODE END Header */

/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"
#include "stm32l0xx_it.h"
/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */
#include "Remote.h"
/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN TD */

/* USER CODE END TD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */

/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/* External variables --------------------------------------------------------*/
extern PCD_HandleTypeDef hpcd_USB_FS;
/* USER CODE BEGIN EV */

/* USER CODE END EV */

/******************************************************************************/
/*           Cortex-M0+ Processor Interruption and Exception Handlers          */ 
/******************************************************************************/
/**
  * @brief This function handles Non maskable interrupt.
  */
void NMI_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN NonMaskableInt_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END NonMaskableInt_IRQn 0 */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN NonMaskableInt_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END NonMaskableInt_IRQn 1 */
}

/**
  * @brief This function handles Hard fault interrupt.
  */
void HardFault_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN HardFault_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END HardFault_IRQn 0 */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE BEGIN W1_HardFault_IRQn 0 */
    /* USER CODE END W1_HardFault_IRQn 0 */
  }
}

/**
  * @brief This function handles System service call via SWI instruction.
  */
void SVC_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SVC_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END SVC_IRQn 0 */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SVC_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END SVC_IRQn 1 */
}

/**
  * @brief This function handles Pendable request for system service.
  */
void PendSV_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN PendSV_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END PendSV_IRQn 0 */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN PendSV_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END PendSV_IRQn 1 */
}

/**
  * @brief This function handles System tick timer.
  */
void SysTick_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysTick_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END SysTick_IRQn 0 */
  HAL_IncTick();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysTick_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END SysTick_IRQn 1 */
}

/******************************************************************************/
/* STM32L0xx Peripheral Interrupt Handlers                                    */
/* Add here the Interrupt Handlers for the used peripherals.                  */
/* For the available peripheral interrupt handler names,                      */
/* please refer to the startup file (startup_stm32l0xx.s).                    */
/******************************************************************************/

/**
  * @brief This function handles EXTI line 0 and line 1 interrupts.
  */
void EXTI0_1_IRQHandler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN EXTI0_1_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END EXTI0_1_IRQn 0 */
  HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler(GPIO_PIN_0);
  HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler(GPIO_PIN_1);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN EXTI0_1_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END EXTI0_1_IRQn 1 */
}

/**
  * @brief This function handles EXTI line 2 and line 3 interrupts.
  */
void EXTI2_3_IRQHandler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN EXTI2_3_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END EXTI2_3_IRQn 0 */
  HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler(GPIO_PIN_2);
  HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler(GPIO_PIN_3);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN EXTI2_3_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END EXTI2_3_IRQn 1 */
}

/**
  * @brief This function handles EXTI line 4 to 15 interrupts.
  */
void EXTI4_15_IRQHandler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN EXTI4_15_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END EXTI4_15_IRQn 0 */
  HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler(GPIO_PIN_4);
  HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler(GPIO_PIN_5);
  HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler(GPIO_PIN_6);
  HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler(GPIO_PIN_7);
  HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler(GPIO_PIN_8);
  HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler(GPIO_PIN_9);
  HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler(GPIO_PIN_10);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN EXTI4_15_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END EXTI4_15_IRQn 1 */
}

/**
  * @brief This function handles USB event interrupt / USB wake-up interrupt through EXTI line 18.
  */
void USB_IRQHandler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USB_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END USB_IRQn 0 */
  HAL_PCD_IRQHandler(&hpcd_USB_FS);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USB_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END USB_IRQn 1 */
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */
void HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback(uint16_t GPIO_Pin)
{
    switch(GPIO_Pin)
    {
    case PWR_Pin:
        sendData(0x57e3e817);
    }
}
/* USER CODE END 1 */
/************************ (C) COPYRIGHT STMicroelectronics *****END OF FILE****/
```

*Remote.c*

```
/*
 * Remote.c
 *
 *  Created on: Jun 3, 2020

 */

#include "Remote.h"

void delay_us(uint16_t time)
{
    TIM6->ARR = time;
    TIM6->CR1 |= (1<<0);

    while(TIM6->CR1 & 1);
}

void sendStart()
{
    HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim2, TIM_CHANNEL_1);
    delay_us(9000);
    HAL_TIM_PWM_Stop(&htim2, TIM_CHANNEL_1);
    delay_us(4500);
}


void sendData(uint32_t data)
{
    uint32_t dataMask = (1<<31);
    sendStart();

    for(;dataMask > 0;dataMask=dataMask>>1)
    {

        bool bit = dataMask & data;
        if(bit)
        {
            HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim2, TIM_CHANNEL_1);
            delay_us(562);
            HAL_TIM_PWM_Stop(&htim2, TIM_CHANNEL_1);
            delay_us(1687);
        }
        else
        {
            HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim2, TIM_CHANNEL_1);
            delay_us(562);
            HAL_TIM_PWM_Stop(&htim2, TIM_CHANNEL_1);
            TIM2->CCMR1 |= (1<<6);
            TIM2->CCMR1 &= ~((1<<5)|(1<<4));
            delay_us(562);


        }

    }
    sendStop();
}

void sendStop()
{
    HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim2, TIM_CHANNEL_1);
    delay_us(562);
    HAL_TIM_PWM_Stop(&htim2, TIM_CHANNEL_1);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can guess only. The `HAL_...` use `HAL_Delay` functions which requires internal variable to be increased in the SYSTICK interrupt handler. Priority of the SYSTICK has to be higher than the priority of the interrupt where those functions are called from.